# VBA Excel 2016 - Run-time error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am trying to write code to copy and paste data from one sheet to the master sheet in the same workbook based on 5 drop down lists (using data validation) on the master sheet and have written this code for it as below, however every time I get the run time 1004 error and don't know how to solve it, is there a way to fix this?

```
Private Sub GO_Click()
Worksheets("Dashboard").Select
If Worksheets("Dashboard").Range(B3) = "National Gallery" And 
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range(B4) = "unframed" And 
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range(B7) = "Product Costings" And 
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range(B5) = "N/A" And 
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range(B6) = "N/A" Then
Worksheets("(7b)").Activate
Worksheets("(7b)").Range(A8, F23).Copy_
Destination = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range(D11)

Else: MsgBox ("No Data")

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are referring to cell `B3` when using `...Range(B3) = ...` then you need to included inverted commas. So it would be `...Range("B3") = ...` currently it will assume that `B4` is a variable and it probably has nothing assigned in it.

Comment: This should be a compile error, if you add `Option Explicit` on the top. Thus advise - add `Option Explicit` and rewrite the code until it can be compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after copy the line put this :

```
Worksheets("Dashboard").activate
range("D11").pasteSpecial xlpastevalues 'or just paste depends on your need
```

don't forget to put " inside range("x")
hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Jean-Pierre Oosthuizen is correct. adding commas to your ranges will fix the 1004 issue for you. The below code should now work for you.

```
Private Sub GO_Click()
Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
If Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B3") = "National Gallery" And _
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B4") = "unframed" And _
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B7") = "Product Costings" And _
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B5") = "N/A" And _
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B6") = "N/A" Then
Worksheets("(7b)").Activate
Worksheets("(7b)").Range("A8", "F232").Copy_
Destination = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("D11")

Else: MsgBox ("No Data")

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless `B3`, `B4`, etc are global variables, you're asking for `.Range(null)` which isn't valid. As [@Jean-PierreOosthuizen said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095341/vba-excel-2016-run-time-error-1004#comment79152593_46095341), you want `.Range("B3")`.

Also unless you have a WorkSheet *named* "(7b)" (with the parens "()" included), your reference to `Worksheets("(7b)")` will fail next.

---

Bonus code review:

*Please* work on proper indentation - it makes your code *much* more readable! Future you (like you a week from now) will thank present you for doing so. [Rubberduck VBA](http://rubberduckvba.com/)<sup>*</sup> will do that for you as well as pointing out lots of other things that will make your code better, like:

- Eliminate `Worksheets("Dashboard").Select` - You're doing an excellent job of explicitly specifying all your worksheet references, so you don't need to `.Select` one.
- Eliminate `Worksheets("(7b)").Activate` - Same as above
- Eliminate the multiline `Else: MsgBox ("No Data")` and replace it with two lines of code - it's much more readable.

<sup>*</sup>I'm not yet a contributor to the Rubberduck project, but I'm a happy user and have learned quite a bit about better coding from them